# Sencha Touch 2 overlay showBy html div

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How can I use this to show by a div:

Html

```
<div class='clickable'>Tap me</div>
```

JS code (tap is connected to the div element above)

```
tap      : function(e) {
    overlay = Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype: 'panel',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        modal: true,
        hideOnMaskTap: true,
        hidden: true,
        width: 260,
        height:'70%',
        html: 'STUFF!!',
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        scrollable: true,
        items: [
            {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                title: 'Overlay Title'
            }
        ]
    });

    overlay.showBy(e.getTarget());
}
```

However this is a nightmare, I'll get these errors with `e.getTarget()` or `e.target`, it does work with `.show()` but its positioning is then wrong. What is the correct way to do this?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableCellElement> has no method 'getPageBox'
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [event delegation](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?176239-HOWTO-Adding-Event-Listeners-to-Component-Elements) on your HTML div tag. So you can give your div tag an id:

`<div class='clickable' id='myId'>Tap me</div>`

```
listeners : {
    tap: {
        fn: function() {},
        element: 'element',
        delegate: '#myId'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hack it by overlaying an invisible Ext.Button over your html div! You'll just have to add a painted function to render the new button...

```
 tpl: '<div class='clickable'>Tap me</div>'
 .......


 listeners: {

        painted : function(){
            var clickable     = Ext.DomQuery.select('.pageClass .clickable')[0];

                var invisibleButton = new Ext.Button({
                    text:           'whatever',
                    renderTo:       clickable,
                    cls:            'something',
                    width:          '100%',
                              // set styles as transparent bg, no border etc...
                    handler: function(){
                        var overlay = Ext.Viewport.add({
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            left: 0,
                            top: 0,
                            modal: true,
                            hideOnMaskTap: true,
                            hidden: true,
                            width: 260,
                            height:'70%',
                            html: 'STUFF!!',
                            styleHtmlContent: true,
                            scrollable: true,
                            items: [
                                {
                                    docked: 'top',
                                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                                    title: 'Overlay Title'
                                }
                            ]
                        });

                        overlay.showBy(this);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Tested and working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this:

```
tap : function(e) {
    var overlay = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
      xtype: 'panel',
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      modal: true,
      hideOnMaskTap: true,
      hidden: true,
      width: 260,
      height:'70%',
      html: 'STUFF!!',
      styleHtmlContent: true,
      scrollable: true,
      items: [
        {
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: 'Overlay Title'
        }
    ]
   });

overlay.showBy(e.getTarget());
}
```

That is to say, do not add to viewport ... create the panel instead.